# Failed to minify the code from this file: ./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:296:13

Tags: javascript, webpack, npm-build

when i npm run build alert:Failed to minify the code from this file: ./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:296:13,because i import antd/g2,i have upgrade babel7 and my local node 20,npm is 9

how to fix it and can build successful

Comment: Please provide more context or code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.